# Powershell - Remove text and capitalise some letters

Tags: powershell

Been scratching my head on this one...

I'd like to remove .com and capitalize S and T from: "sometext.com"

So output would be Some Text

Thank you in advance

Comment: getting rid of the `.com` is easy ... how do you decide where to split the remaining string? [*grin*]

Comment: Please show us your code. Did you try regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of this you can use the replace() member of the String object. 
The syntax is:

```
$string = $string.replace('what you want replaced', 'what you will replace it with')
```

Replace can be used to erase things by using blank quotes '' for the second argument. That's how you can get rid of .com

```
$string = $string.replace('.com','')
```

It can also be used to insert things. You can insert a space between some and text like this:

```
$string = $string.replace('et', 'e t')
```

Note that using replace does NOT change the original variable. The command below will print "that" to your screen, but the value of $string will still be "this"

```
$string = 'this'
$string.replace('this', 'that')
```

You have to set the variable to the new value with =

```
$string = "this"
$string = $string.replace("this", "that")
```

This command will change the value of $string to that.

The tricky part here comes in changing the first t to capital T without changing the last t. With strings, replace() replaces every instance of the text.

```
$string = "text"
$string = $string.replace('t', 'T')
```

This will set $string to TexT. To get around this, you can use Regex. Regex is a complex topic. Here just know that Regex objects look like strings, but their replace method works a little differently. You can add a number as a third argument to specify how many items to replace

```
$string = "aaaaaa"
[Regex]$reggie = 'a'
$string = $reggie.replace($string,'a',3)
```

This code sets $string to AAAaaa.

So here's the final code to change sometext.com to Some Text.

```
$string = 'sometext.com'
#Use replace() to remove text.
$string = $string.Replace('.com','')
#Use replace() to change text
$string = $string.Replace('s','S')
#Use replace() to insert text.
$string = $string.Replace('et', 'e t')
#Use a Regex object to replace the first instance of a string.
[regex]$pattern = 't'
$string = $pattern.Replace($string, 'T', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve isn't well-defined, but here's a concise **PowerShell *Core* solution**:

```
PsCore> 'sometext.com' -replace '\.com$' -replace '^s|t(?!$)', { $_.Value.ToUpper() }

SomeText
```

- `-replace '\.com$'` removes a literal trailing `.com` from your input string.
- `-replace '^s|t(?!$), { ... }` matches an `s` char. at the start (`^`), and a `t` that is *not* (`!`) at the end (`$`); `(?!...)` is a so-called negative [look-ahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that looks ahead in the input string without including what it finds in the overall match.
- Script block `{ $_.Value.ToUpper() }` is called for each match, and converts the match to uppercase.
- `-replace` (a.k.a `-ireplace`) is case-INsensitive by default; use `-creplace` for case-SENSITIVE replacements.

For more information about PowerShell's `-replace` operator see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

Passing a *script block* (`{ ... }`) to *dynamically* determine the replacement string isn't supported in Windows PowerShell, so a ***Windows PowerShell* solution requires direct use of the .NET `[regex]` class**:

```
WinPs> [regex]::Replace('sometext.com' -replace '\.com$', '^s|t(?!$)', { param($m) $m.Value.ToUpper() })

SomeText
```